# IMAGE_NT_HEADERS in C# (incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field)

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the IMAGE_NT_HEADERS to work.

For that I created a struct like this:

```
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public char[] Signature;

            //Incorrect aligned error if uncommented
            [FieldOffset(4)]
            public IMAGE_FILE_HEADER FileHeader;

            [FieldOffset(24)]
            public IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 OptionalHeader;

            private string _Signature {
                get { return new string(Signature); }
            }

            public bool isValid {
                get { return _Signature == "PE\0\0" && OptionalHeader.Magic == MagicType.IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC; }
            }
        }
```

With an IMAGE_FILE_HEADER struct like this:

```
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 20)]
        public struct IMAGE_FILE_HEADER {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public UInt16 Machine;
            [FieldOffset(2)]
            public UInt16 NumberOfSections;
            [FieldOffset(4)]
            public UInt32 TimeDateStamp;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public UInt32 PointerToSymbolTable;
            [FieldOffset(12)]
            public UInt32 NumberOfSymbols;
            [FieldOffset(16)]
            public UInt16 SizeOfOptionalHeader;
            [FieldOffset(18)]
            public UInt16 Characteristics;
        }
```

But trying to run the script I get following error message:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64' from assembly 'Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 4 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.'

When commenting out the code with the IMAGE_FILE_HEADER I am able to correctly compile the program and everything gets loaded as wanted. But I need the FileHeaders.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You set size = 20, but you use only 18. Try with additional UInt16

Comment: But isn't the size 20? 4*UInt16 = 4*2 = 8 + 3*UInt32 = 8 + 12 = 20?

Comment: It should be `[FieldOffset(16)]
            public UInt16 SizeOfOptionalHeader;` and `[FieldOffset(18)]
            public UInt16 Characteristics;`

Comment: Personally, I would avoid using `SizeConst`-arrays if possible (also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54240120/21567)). Github has examples how to do this with a simple `UInt32` [here](https://github.com/dotnet/arcade/blob/8f84a71d57b9735340856e0b8e56c7cc0f2db6b0/src/SignCheck/Microsoft.SignCheck/Interop/PortableExecutable/ImageNTHeaders.cs#L47) like the native code would do.

Comment: @viveknuna thanks, I just found that out too. Unfortunately it still throws the same error

Comment: @qweqwe are you sure, is that exact same error?

Comment: @viveknuna The error message is: "'IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64' from assembly 'Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 4 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this. you are using wrong value

```
[FieldOffset(16)]
public UInt16 SizeOfOptionalHeader;
[FieldOffset(18)]
public UInt16 Characteristics;
```

Comment: sadly still receiving the same error message: "'IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64' from assembly 'Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 4 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.'"

Comment: try with what @chritian has suggested

Comment: have you tried by removing line `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]`?

Comment: try this once, what are you getting when you comment this line `public char[] Signature;` I just want to see whether is it due to the first property. Otherwise you ca try by changing the order of declaration of properties

Comment: I changed the line to [FieldOffset(0)] public UInt32 Signature; now and it works. Though I am not sure how to verify the signature now, since it is always false now. Is there a way to cast UInt32 to a string?